# iframe of TinyMCE editor is removed from DOM after moving the editor

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, tinymce, dnd-kit

I have a sortable collection of TinyMce editors and when an editor is moved, this one doesn't work anymore.

The TinyMCE editor iframe turn empty after drag end event but I don't understand why.

The editor toolbar is here but doesn't work and the content disappear without possibility of typing in it again.

Is there a way to reinitialize the dragged editor with his initial content after drag end event.

I'm using Reactjs and @dnd-kit/sortable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving the iFrame editor around the DOM is not supported. If you want to move the editor you can achieve this by removing the editor with `remove()` and reinitializing it with `init()` once it has been moved.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.root/#remove
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/apis/tinymce.root/#init

The other alternative is to run TinyMCE in inline mode:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/use-tinymce-inline/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I init() the Editor after call remove() method, knowing that I'm using tinymce.Editor ReactJS Component ? I already try to use inline mode, but this one doesnt work on mobile devices, according to the documentation. Can you give me an example of the reitinialization case please ?

Comment: Here is a basic example of using init() and remove() to get you started: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/7niaab